# How we can return extra parameter with the 'HTTP_REFERER' URL in Django views?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-registration

```
url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') 

return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

This URL is used to redirect to the current page and I want to send a parameter with it. How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.parse

params = {"test": 1, "q": "some search string"}
query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
if not url:
    url = request.META.get('some-other-header')
url += "?" + query_string
```